# vim-highlight: cannot match regular expression lookbehind

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to use the vim-syntax to configure some custom highlight for my c++ project.

I've created a file named `cpp.vim` and put it into `~/.vim/syntax/`. And to highlight the function name, I put

```
syn match    cCustomParen    "?=(" contains=cParen,cCppParen
syn match    cCustomFunc     "\w\+\s*(\@=" contains=cCustomParen
hi CustomFunc guifg=NONE guibg=NONE guisp=NONE gui=bold ctermfg=lightyellow ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold    
hi def link cCustomFunc CustomFunc
```

into the file `cpp.vim`, it works as expected.

Now I'm trying to highlight the class name.

Here is what I've tried:

```
hi CustomClassName guifg=NONE guibg=NONE guisp=NONE gui=bold ctermfg=lightyellow ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold
syn match cCustomClassName "(?<=^class\s)\w\+"
hi def link cCustomClassName CustomClassName
```

However, the class name is still white.

`(?<=^class\s)\w\+` is trying to match a word, which is following a `class` and a space. For example, this regex can match things like `class Test` ignoring `class`, which is exactly what regular expression lookbehind should do.

I've tested this regex with some online tool and it works perfectly. So I don't know why it can not work for the vim syntax config.

Comment: Lookarounds in vim are different in syntax. You should try `\(REGEX\)\@<=` for a positive lookbehind.

Comment: @revo   it works!   thanks a lot. Pose an answer maybe?

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. I found a question that points to the same problem and marked this as a duplicate.